# Connect IdentityServer4 to FoxIDs

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, foxids

I need to connect an existing IdentityServer4 a FoxIDs tenant. How are IdentityServer4 configured as a FoxIDs up-party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct a IdentityServer4 client is configured as a FoxIDs up-party using OpenID Connect.

You can see how IdentityServer4 is configured as an up-party in the [documentation](https://www.foxids.com/docs/up-party-howto-oidc-identityserver). Furthermore, the documentation also reference sample applications showing how to do the integration.